# Manually deploying Umbraco website on IIS - dashboard, js and css not working

Tags: iis, iis-7, umbraco, webmatrix, umbraco7

I have an Umbraco website with an SQl db. I backed up the DB and imported it on the SQL server on the server here. I then copied all the files of my umbraco folder and placed them in a folder on the server here as well.

I then made an 'application' in IIS and gave it an 4.5 application pool (integrated). I linked it to the folder on the server where all of the files are.

When I browse to the site I get to see all the content, also the dynamic content from the DB, but none of the mark up is applied. If I add /umbraco behind it to access the dev dashboard I just get a white page.

I have only been working with it for 5 days and am new to umbraco. IIS on the local server here has no web deploy installed and FTP is also not an option. I developped the website with Webmatrix and web deploy & FTP are the only two publish option it gives me.

Is there something I did wrong or how can I get the website to work properly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umbraco needs to run in Full Trust mode. Make sure that your IIS is configured for Full Trust.

On Features View --> .NET Trust Levels --> Full (internal)

Comment: It is in full trust mode, but I think the problem is with the routing. If I check the network in firefox it says he can't find the css and script folders and such as he looks for it under server/scripts or server/css while it needs to be server:port/css I think. Is this possible ?

Comment: The problem was that my files were not in the root of inetpub. I have them there now. I have another problem now because the website isn't accesible from outside of the server but i'll make a new question for that.